# Detect when Swiping back gets stopped

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

When I click on a button a new ViewController opens and `viewWillAppear` is called, where I change some stuff in my navigationBar.

When I go back to the previous ViewController the `viewWillAppear` method of this ViewController is called and also changes some stuff in my navigationBar.

This works fine. **BUT** when going back with swiping, while swiping the `viewWillAppear` from the previous ViewController is called. When the swiping is not finished as in 'oh I decideded to stay on this viewController', the navigationBar looks wrong because the `viewWillAppear` from the previous viewController got called.

I would need to detect if somebody does the swiping but doesn't `finish` it as in really going back, to undo the navigationBar changes.

Is this possible?

**EDIT** Or in best case it would call the `viewWillAppear` method of the already showing viewController when the user swipes back to the right side too.

I thought the lifecycle would be like this when not finishing a swipe form page two to page one:

```
viewWillDisappear Page Two
viewWillAppear Page One
viewWillDisappear Page One
viewDidDisappear Page One
viewWillAppear Page Two
viewDidAppear Page Two
```

but for me `viewWillDisappear` is never called on Page Two. Also `viewWillAppear` is never called for page two.